# Angular 2 - Kendo UI Dropdown default value

Tags: javascript, angular, drop-down-menu, kendo-ui

I'm trying to create a dropdownlist using Kendo UI, it's working great except for having a default ***selected*** value when the screen loads.

according to their [documentation](http://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/dropdowns/dropdownlist/#toc-use-complex-type-values) my code should look like this:

**HTML:**

```
<kendo-dropdownlist formControlName="description"
                    [data]="definitionData.Languages"
                    [(ngModel)]="languageValue"
                    [textField]="'Value'"
                    [valueField]="'Key'"
                    [value]="2"
                    [valuePrimitive]="true">
</kendo-dropdownlist>
<span class="left col-xs-6">
    <input type="text" id="descriptionField" class="form-control" [value]="getValue(descriptionForm.controls.description.value)" #descriptionField (blur)="updateDescriptionValue(descriptionField.value, languageValue)" />
</span>
```

**COMPONENT:**

```
public descriptionForm: FormGroup = new FormGroup({
    description: new FormControl()
});
```

My dropdown works, but the default selected value is blank when I load the page, and it should be the object with `Key: 2`

*note: I don't want to use `[defaultItem]` since It will just duplicate the item, meaning it will be in the dropdown list 2 times.*

I've tried numerous things, but I can't figure out what I should do!

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why do you use `ngModel` and `value` at the same time? Make sure that `value` is the element of `data`

Comment: @KonradKahl because my form needs to be reactive, and according to the documentation they use `value` to set their default selected value (I want it to be the item where `Key = 2`, which also happens to be the second item in the array

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should choose between `value` and `ngModel` binding. From [documentation](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/dropdowns/dropdownlist/value-binding/):

> The DropDownList does not support the simultaneous usage of the `value` property and the `ngModel` value binding.

**Solution with `value` property:**

1. Delete `ngModel` from HTML.
2. Bind to `valueChange` event and set value in your model.

HTML:

```
<kendo-dropdownlist formControlName="description"
                [data]="definitionData.Languages"
                (valueChange)="handleValue($event)"
                [textField]="'Value'"
                [valueField]="'Key'"
                [value]="2"
                [valuePrimitive]="true">
</kendo-dropdownlist>
```

COMPONENT:

```
handleValue(value) {
    this.languageValue = value;
}
```

**Solution with `ngModel` property:**

1. Delete `value` from HTML.
2. Set default value in your model.

HTML:

```
<kendo-dropdownlist formControlName="description"
                [data]="definitionData.Languages"
                [(ngModel)]="languageValue"
                [textField]="'Value'"
                [valueField]="'Key'"
                [valuePrimitive]="true">
</kendo-dropdownlist>
```

COMPONENT:

```
constructor(){
    this.languageValue = 2;
}
```